# How can create Visualizer for android 2.3.3 audio recoder

Tags: android

Visualizer Mediaplayer link

```
public void link(MediaPlayer player)
  {
    if(player == null)
    {
      throw new NullPointerException("Cannot link to null MediaPlayer");
    }

    // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to our media player.
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(player.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

    // Pass through Visualizer data to VisualizerView
    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
        updateVisualizer(bytes);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
        updateVisualizerFFT(bytes);
      }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
        Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, true);

    // Enabled Visualizer and disable when we're done with the stream
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);

  }
```

How can I create the Visualizer for android Audio Recorder 2.3.3? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
public void link(AudioRecorder recorder)
{

// Create the Visualizer object and attach it to our media player.
mVisualizer = new Visualizer(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
```

But my problem is that `recorder.getAudioSessionId()` method only is available in API level 16 (Jellybean) and above, while I'm targeting Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread). Any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create visualizer for android Audio Recorder 2.3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460548/create-visualizer-for-android-audio-recorder-2-3-3)

Comment: Yesterday some told my question  was not clear.That's why I asking the same question clearly

Comment: did you get the answer to this question?